# Multiple Condition Formula

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm working on a project as part of a data clean up program, currently in my spreadsheet there are six columns that state if the data entry is erroneous. These columns are based on formula that checks the entry for certain conditions.

What I need to do if write a formula that shows what issues are affecting a data entry and too list them in that cell.

```
=if(u2 = "Domain Mismatch" , TEXT(u2,),......
```

so if the check for a domain mismatch is positive it will display "Domain Mismatch" in the issue column, is there a way to combine the six other columns so if four of them flag the entry as wrong they will be displayed in the issue category?

Comment: So if you have 4 errors for a given entry, you want to concatenate the 4 of them? Just use the concatenation operator, `=U2&V2&W2&" some text..."`

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that